# Interactive Gambler's Ruin with Dash and Plotly

Tags: probability, statistics, finance, python, gambling

I created this interactive dashboard to show the concept of gamblers ruin and how you can go bust very quickly even with favourable odds.

I would love some feedback:

- Are there any other graphs or stats you would find useful/important?
- Is it easy to understand? How could it be made more user friendly?
- General feedback

https://gamblers-ruin1.herokuapp.com/

Thank you

Comment: Your dashboard illustrates the point you are trying to make about the Kelly criterion.  If you do have an excellent strategy (e.g. a probability of winning a bet of $70\%$ and staking $40\%$ of your bankroll each time) then you might want to consider showing the second chart with a logarithmic scale (perhaps as an additional chart).   You might also want to consider showing the mean, at least in the summary box and perhaps in the first chart.

Comment: Thanks, what would be the benefit of showing the second chart with a logarithmic scale?
Im wary of showing the mean because I think it can be misleading as its not a good measure of centrality when there are such huge outliers.

Comment: In the case of $70\%,40\%$ the second chart looks as if only a few people won something when in fact everyone does

Comment: Understood thanks